# Making a client-server chat - running into issues with connecting client to client

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to make a multiple-client chatting program. Im following the Oracle tutorial on Custom Networking, but its not really what I am looking for. So far, I have no code of my own to share, all of it is copied from the Oracle tutorial and I think pasting it here would be a copyright infringement(??).

link at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html+

client code link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java

anyway, I have the server-client working where the server tells knock knock jokes, the client reads and prints, then the user replies and so on. how would i start to edit it to have the client talk to the other clients directly?

im sorry, i have no background with networking at all. if anyone can direct me to a informative source better suited to my goals i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

as in the Knock-Knock example, each client connects to the server, but they not mutually directly connected.

There is a solution to make a forwarding sever :Arrange each client an id, and clients use id to identify their talking partners.

To do this, you have to modify the client to server data format from a plain string to a tuple like (String,Id).  And, when the server receive the data, it parses out the id, get the corresponding client socket and then write the data.

Answer (score 0):

The required level of complexity just went up a notch as your going to need some sort of "interprocess communications" infrastructure to allow client to client communication (possibly via sockets marshalled by the server?)